# Union Type causes "type lacks a call signature" error

Tags: typescript

I want to call an array sort function with two different types of arrays in Typescript, by using a Union Type. The function call works for the separate types but not for the Union Type?

```
    this.shuffle(stringArray);  // array of strings
    this.shuffle(StudentArray); // array of student objects

    // this works
    shuffle(arr:Student[]) {
        arr.sort(() => (Math.random() - 0.5))
    }

    // this works
    shuffle(arr:string[]) {
        arr.sort(() => (Math.random() - 0.5))
    }

    // this gives an error
    shuffle(arr:Student[] | string[]) {
        arr.sort(() => (Math.random() - 0.5))
    }
```

**Error**

```
Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature.
```

Comment: Try `(Student | string)[]` - see e.g. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7294

Comment: Thanks that was it

Comment: @jonrsharpe Could you make your comment an answer so it can be accepted as correct?

Answer (score 2):

Change `arr:Student[] | string[]` to `(Student | string)[]`

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to use ForEach with `arr: string[] | string[][]`... you would think that would work... but i needed to change it to `arr: (string | string[])[]`. Pretty silly that it isnt smart enough to know both are arrays.